# Error 534 al enviar un email con Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, nodemailer

Tengo un proyecto web donde se crean unos eventos deportivos y al momento de crear un evento tengo que enviar un correo, es primera vez que uso nodemailer.

estoy haciendo pruebas del envio entonces para eso tengo un **link** que al hacer ***click*** el controlador de la **url** debe enviar el correo. pero me sale error.
 Los codigos son los siguientes:

**Link:**

```
<a href="/admin/enviar">enviar correo</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',

    auth: {
        user: 'danielroca7derc@gmail.com',
        pass: '*********'
    }
});
router.get('/enviar', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("voy a enviar un correo");
        var mailOptions = {
            from: '"ColSport ?" <danielroca7derc@gmail.com>', // sender address
            to: 'danielroca_7@hotmail.com, danielroca7derc@gmail.com', // list of receivers
            subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
            text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
            html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
         };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
        });
        res.redirect('back');
    })
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que no has activado la opción para [acceder al SMTP desde aplicaciones menos seguras](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). Actívalo y vuelve a intentar.

Comment: Hombre Gracias! Si funciona pero me deja pensando es el mensaje que sale en el link: 

Aplicaciones menos seguras 
Algunos dispositivos y aplicaciones utilizan una tecnología de inicio de sesión menos segura, lo cual hace que tu cuenta sea más vulnerable, por lo que te recomendamos que desactives el acceso de estas aplicaciones. Si, a pesar del riesgo que ello supone, quieres utilizarlas, puedes activar el acceso.

Comment: Claro, es que, se supone que si activas ésto, tu cuenta GMail será accedida desde cualquier dispositivo en el que se ejecute el backend. Pero pierde cuidado, tu cuenta será accedida solo desde tu aplicación, así que no la pones en riesgo. Si te sirvió mi comentario y estás de acuerdo, la puedo mover a respuesta para que la marques como correcta.

Comment: Dale, ponla como respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Es posible que Google **bloquee el acceso de algunas apps o dispositivos** que no usen los estándares de seguridad modernos. Al bloquearlos, se mantiene la seguridad de tu cuenta, ya que **es más sencillo acceder sin autorización** a estas apps y dispositivos.

El problema se debe a que no has activado el [acceso a tu cuenta desde aplicaciones menos seguras](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). Una vez hecho ésto podrás loguearte con GMail desde cualquier cliente. Para evitar activar ésta opción en tu cuenta, necesitarás dar seguridad extra a tu aplicación, en concreto brindar una manera de autenticar con Google vía crifrado para que no sea posible interceptar los datos de ingreso. En [ésta pregunta](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/what-are-the-dangers-of-allowing-less-secure-apps-to-access-my-google-account) puedes leer con más detalle los riegos que pueden existir.